# Multiple imports as object keys

Tags: javascript, node.js, babeljs

As far as I understand ES6 imports, the following are possible:

```
import * as name from "module-name";
import { export1 as alias1 } from "module-name";
import { export1 , export2 } from "module-name";
```

I want to know if it's possible to alias multiple imports as an object like this:

```
import { export1 , export2 } as name from "module-name";
```

So that `module-name`'s exports can be accessed as keys of the `name` object like this:

```
name.export1();
```

Comment: All the different ways to import are listed [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import). What you want doesn't seem to be included.

Comment: @Barmar that seems to be the case, that's why I asked if there was a way to do such a thing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the description on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) this is not possible.
but maybe you can tackle it through the export.
for instance you might have:

```
export const modulesObject = {
    moduleOne,
    moduleTwo
};
```

and on the import side have:

```
import { modulesObject as myName} from 'module-name';
```

and use would be:

```
myName.moduleOne()
```

etc..

Comment: I suspect he's trying to be selective when importing, without changing the exports.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this with splitting the command into two lines:

```
import { export1 , export2 } from "module-name";
const name = { export1 , export2 };
```

Then you can access the exports as keys of the name object like this:

```
name.export1();
```